# Changing arrow tips in XYpic to Lucida Bright ones

Tags: fonts, xy-pic

I am producing a document with [Lucida Bright fonts](http://tug.org/store/lucida/lucida-sample.pdf) and using `xypic` to produce diagrams. The thing is the Lucida arrow tips are very different (much prettier!) from the ones in `xypic`, which amounts to unsettling lack of consistency through the text... Is there any way to make `xypic` use Lucida's arrows?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Xy-pic uses a special font for the arrow tips; it's not able to fill arbitrary paths. You may want to try `tikz-cd` for commutative diagrams.

Answer (score 5):

Xy-pic uses a special font for the arrow tips and it's not able to fill arbitrary paths.

You may want to try tikz-cd for commutative diagrams.